# Bootstrap list-group states (danger, success,...) based on Value

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to Change the color/state of a Bootstrap list based on the number in the column.

something like:

```
   =< 25 = success
    > 25 = warning
    > 30 = danger
```

Static list im working with right now.

```
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">18</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">26</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">33</li>
```

I'm new to HTML and Javascript and couldn't figure it out by myself. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: So what have css have you tried so far?  Results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. This adds the class `list-group-item-X` where X is either 'success', 'warning' or 'danger' depending on the elements number

```js
let items = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");
for(let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  let number = parseInt(items[i].innerHTML);
  let type = "";
  if(number <= 25) {
    type = "success";
  } 
  if(number > 25) {
    type = "warning";
  }
  
  if(number > 30) {
    type = "danger"
  }
  items[i].classList.add("list-group-item-" +type)
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<li class="list-group-item">18</li>
<li class="list-group-item">26</li>
<li class="list-group-item">33</li>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works. Much appreciated!

Comment: No worries!! :)